# Which port must I ask to open to clone a git repository from bitbucket?

Tags: vpn, git, firewall

We're deploying a project on a VPN of a customer.

We must do a common

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repo_name>.git
```

Actually we cannot because git cannot reach bitbucket.

We resolved first issue asking that server must be able to resolve bitbucket.org, so server must contact a dns in the "wan".

But now the mantainer of customer's infrastructure asked us which ports to open.

I have not this answer so I ask you, kindly: **why port must I ask to open to be able to clone a repository from bitbucket?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Git, locations in the form of `[user@]server:path` are interpreted as **SSH** addresses (and the 'clone' tool literally runs `ssh [user@]server` in the background).

By default, SSH connects to port **22/tcp**, which is the standard SSH port. Git does not change this, and BitBucket's SSH service likewise expects connections on the standard port 22/tcp.

---

However, BitBucket also have an alternate server, `altssh.bitbucket.org`, which accepts SSH connections on port 443/tcp instead (which is normally the HTTPS port, and often is already permitted). In order to use this (e.g. if your sysadmin does not want to allow the standard port 22), you could redirect connections by creating an `~/.ssh/config` which contains:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    HostName altssh.bitbucket.org
    Port 443
    HostkeyAlias bitbucket.org
```

Another alternative is to clone the repository over *actual* HTTPS (which uses port 443/tcp), using a regular `https://` URL that you can find on the repository's page. The disadvantage is that it requires using a password (or some special token) and doesn't support SSH keypairs. (But on the other hand, for *public* repositories it can be more convenient than SSH.)

```
git clone https://<username>@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo_name>.git
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! My network admins have blocked all external traffic on port 22, preventing me from cloning our private repos on Bitbucket. Could you please add some extra help regarding the meaning of the 4 lines in your `~/.ssh/config` file and what they all do and how they work? I have used ssh for years but don't know how to write an ssh config file, nor where the documentation is to learn about it.

Comment: I referenced your answer in mine here: [Cannot `git clone` Bitbucket repo on Windows: `ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable; The fix: route SSH traffic to Bitbucket.org through port 443 instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76925306/4561887)